# AngularJS + MEANJS - Use object model property as array key for filter

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, meanjs

I have a MEANJS app with a CRUD module of countries. When I click on a country from the default list view, it brings me to the view-country.client.view. I have added a field to my model for currencycode. When I click the country it will bring me to a page where I want it to bring up the exchange rate from a json by matching the currencycode field of the Country model with my data from the json import.

```
//view-country.client.view

<section data-ng-controller="CountriesController" data-ng-init="findRate()">
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel panel-dark">
        <div class="panel-heading">Currency</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        {{country.currencycode}}
            <p>The exchange rate is {{exchangeRates.rates['AFN']}}
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>
</section>





//findRate() for data-ng-init in CountriesController

$scope.findRate = function() {

            $scope.country = Countries.get({ 
                    countryId: $stateParams.countryId
                });

            $http.get('http://localhost:3000/rates.json').
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.exchangeRates = data        
            });
        };
```

Everything is working with the JSON import and if I include the countrycode (in this example 'AFN' for Afghanistan), it will return the correct rate. The {{country.currencycode}} brings back AFN from my MongoDB but if i try and embed the {{country.currencycode}} where 'AFN' is, it will not work. I have tried looking at filters but I cannot get those to work. Basically, anytime I click a country, I want it to show only the rate for that country by using the model property as a string for getting the correct object from my array. I have been in forums all day and cannot figure this out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I understood correct, you don't want 'AFG' to be hardcoded here: {{exchangeRates.rates['AFN']}}?

If that's the case have you tried {{exchangeRates.rates[country.currencycode]}}?

Comment: Wow, I had ['country.currencycode'] but never tried it without the '' after trying so many other combinations - what an embarrassing oversight. You were correct - it worked as you suggested. Post as an answer and I will accept! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correct, you don't want 'AFG' to be hardcoded here?

```
{{exchangeRates.rates['AFN']}}
```

If that's the case have you tried this?

```
{{exchangeRates.rates[country.currencycode]}}
```